# Syncronized blocks. DeadLock. Java

Tags: java, deadlock, synchronized

please help me. Where does this code may blocked? 
I think it shouldn't block. The thread, that getItem wait while, 
the detail appears in storage and notify anybody if it get any Item from storage. The thread that putItem notfiy, when 
it puts any detail in storage and wait if it is full. Is it right? 
I think no, as deadlock appears
And sorry for my English. It is not my native language.

```
public class Storage<E> {

ArrayList<E> details;
private Integer limit; //Storage Capacity
final MonitorObject expectItemObject; //objects for synchronization
final MonitorObject expectPlaceObject;

public Storage(Integer limit)
{
    this.limit = limit;
    expectItemObject = new MonitorObject();
    expectPlaceObject = new MonitorObject();
    details = new ArrayList<>(limit);
}
 public Integer getSize()
{
    int detNo=0;
    synchronized (expectPlaceObject)
    {
         synchronized (expectItemObject) {
             detNo =  details.size();
         }
    }
    return detNo;
}
public void putItem(E e) throws InterruptedException
{
    synchronized (expectPlaceObject)
    {
        while (getSize().equals(limit)) { //ensure that we have a place
            expectPlaceObject.wait(); //sleep if storage is full
        }
        synchronized (expectItemObject) { //there is no trouble in inners synchronized, as the second is not blocking.
            details.add(e);
            expectItemObject.notify(); //if anybody,who expect item, sleep, awake him.

        }

    }

}
public   E getItem() throws InterruptedException
{
    E detail;
    synchronized (expectItemObject)
    {
        while (getSize() == 0) {
            expectItemObject.wait(); //sleep if storage is empty
        }
        synchronized (expectPlaceObject) {
            detail= details.remove(0);
            expectPlaceObject.notify(); //if anybody,who expect place sleep, awake him.
        }

    }
    return detail;
}
}
```

Comment: Side note: one crux with locking; human beings are very bad at predicting what will happen. I read your code and checked "is he always requesting the locks in the same order" ... and overlooked that you are doing exactly that. Sometimes these things are really easy, but very often they are not. And then it is **much** faster to create a java dump and analyze that. So my suggestion: learn how to do that; it can save you tremendous amounts of time in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `putItem` and `getItem` you are synchronizing on two different objets, `expectPlaceObject` and `expectItemObject`.

The problem is that you are synchronizing on them in a different order in the two methods. What can happen is the following:

1. Thread A calls `putItem` and locks `expectedItemObject`
2. Meanwhile Thread B calls `getItem` and locks `expectedPlaceObject`
3. Next both threads want to lock an object that the other thread already has locked which results in a deadlock.

A good way to investigate deadlocks is to use [jstack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html) to take a thread dump of the process. The output will list your deadlocks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your getSize() method with this:

```
public Integer getSize() {
    return details.size();
}
```